# python tornado.web.uimodules not rendering with jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, tornado

I'm running tornado on a simple web app. Currently, I'm trying to create a user module to display logged in user info on the navbar.html component which is included on base.html.

I created a uimodules.py file, added my Menu class

```
import tornado.web

class Menu(tornado.web.UIModule):
    def render(self):
    return '<div>THE MODULE HAS ARRIVED</div>'
```

Then imported this in my app.py

```
from uimodules import Menu
```

in my settings dict I have

```
"ui_modules": {"Menu": Menu}
```

My understanding is that now, the Menu module should be accessible to my entire app and I should be able to add ...

```
{% module Menu() %}
```

... tag to include this module. When I run the app I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1509, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "app.py", line 69, in get
    self.render_template("/pages/index.html", {"login": login, "user": user})
  File "app.py", line 60, in render_template
    self.write(template.render(**context))
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/devmode/Documents/projects/tornado_starter/myapp/templates/components/navbar.html", line 6, in template
    {% module Menu() %}
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1005, in render
    return concat(self.root_render_func(self.new_context(vars)))
  File "/Users/devmode/Documents/projects/tornado_starter/myapp/templates/pages/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
  File "/Users/devmode/Documents/projects/tornado_starter/myapp/templates/base.html", line 17, in top-level template code
    {% include 'components/navbar.html' %}
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/devmode/Documents/projects/tornado_starter/myapp/templates/components/navbar.html", line 6, in template
    {% module Menu() %}
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse
    return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 896, in parse
    result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 878, in subparse
    rv = self.parse_statement()
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 144, in parse_statement
    self.fail_unknown_tag(token.value, token.lineno)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 97, in fail_unknown_tag
    return self._fail_ut_eof(name, self._end_token_stack, lineno)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 90, in _fail_ut_eof
    self.fail(' '.join(message), lineno)
  File "/Users/devmode/.virtualenvs/tornado_starter/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 59, in fail
    raise exc(msg, lineno, self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'module'.
```

I'm following setups I've seen on github

https://github.com/sunrize531/cherry-forms/blob/master/cherryforms/widgets.py

and the tornado documentation

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html

Answer (score 0):

Tornado's `UIModules` are a feature of the Tornado template system and will not work with other template systems like jinja2. (it would probably be possible to build some sort of adapter for this, but to my knowledge no one has).